# WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_KEYDOWN message are not receiving in Modeless dialogbox Win32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm developing a Win32 application to capture video using Windows Media Foundation. I have to display **Play/Pause/Stop** bitmap image on video window with transparent. I have created a modeless dialog box and shown the transparent image on the dialog using below code.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{ 
    int wmID;
    switch (unMessage)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
         switch(LOWORD(wParam))
         {
           case ID_BTN_VIDEOSTART:              
                 InitModelessDialog();
           break;
         }
         break;     
     }
     return CallWindowProc ( g_lpfnWndProc, hWnd, unMessage, wParam, lParam );
}

void InitModelessDialog()
{
     DIBSECTION ds;
     DWORD dwFlag = MID_EXT_STYLES | MID_CLR_KEY | MID_ALPHA_VAL;

     g_hWndVideoPause = CreateDialog(g_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DLG_VIDEORECORD), g_hwndPreview, DlgProc_VideoPause);

    g_hPauseBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(g_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP_PAUSE), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0);
    GetObject(g_hPauseBmp, sizeof(ds), &ds);

    g_hPauseDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    SelectObject(g_hPauseDC, g_hPauseBmp);

    if(dwFlag & MID_EXT_STYLES)
      SetWindowLong(g_hWndVideoPause, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(g_hWndVideoPause, GWL_EXSTYLE) | (WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT));

   if(dwFlag & (MID_CLR_KEY | MID_ALPHA_VAL))
   {
       DWORD dwTemp = 0;

       if(dwFlag & MID_ALPHA_VAL)
        dwTemp = LWA_ALPHA;

       if(dwFlag & MID_CLR_KEY)
        dwTemp |= LWA_COLORKEY;

       SetLayeredWindowAttributes(g_hWndVideoPause, UI_COLOR_KEY, (255 * UI_TRANSPARENCY_PERCENT) / 100, dwTemp);
   }

   SetParent(g_hWndVideoPause,g_hwndPreview);

   dlgWidth = ds.dsBm.bmWidth;
   dlgHeight = ds.dsBm.bmHeight;

   SetWindowPos(g_hWndVideoPause, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, ds.dsBm.bmWidth, ds.dsBm.bmHeight, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE);
   HDC hDlgDC = GetDC(g_hWndVideoPause);
   StretchBlt(hDlgDC, 0, 0, dlgWidth, dlgHeight, g_hPauseDC, 0, 0, ds.dsBm.bmWidth, ds.dsBm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY); 
   ReleaseDC(g_hWndVideoPause, hDlgDC);

   if(g_hPauseDC)
   {
      DeleteDC(g_hPauseDC);
      g_hPauseDC = NULL;
   }

   if(g_hPauseBmp)
   {
      DeleteObject(g_hPauseBmp);
      g_hPauseBmp = NULL;
  }
}

 INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc_VideoPause(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
 {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    switch (message)
    {
       case WM_INITDIALOG:
           return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
       case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HDC hDC = GetDC(hDlg);
            if(g_hPauseDC)
            {
                StretchBlt(hDC, 0, 0, dlgWidth, dlgHeight, g_hPauseDC, 0, 0, dlgWidth, dlgHeight, SRCCOPY);                         
            }
            ReleaseDC(hDlg, hDC);
        }
        break;
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
    {
        return 1;
    }
    break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        OutputDebugString(L"DlgProc_VideoPause WM_LBUTTONDOWN pressed\r\n");
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        OutputDebugString(L"DlgProc_VideoPause WM_KEYDOWN pressed\r\n");
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

When clicking on the drawn image, WM_KEYDOWN event is going to parent window. I wanna receive the WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_KEYDOWN event in my dialog proc window.What I have to do to receive this notification in my dialog proc?

I didn't create my dialog as Child window since I couldn't apply transparent for my child dialog.So only I'm creating a modeless dialog box.

Am I missing anything here?Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is complicated because mouse clicks and keyboard button presses work pretty differently, so I think you've got (at least) two different problems here.  You're not getting the keyboard messages because the focus is on a different window, and there's not enough information here to figure out how to solve that.  You might not be getting the mouse clicks  if your window has a transparent style.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Adrian. I think You have used Windows media player app. In that app,they would have used transparent button for video play/stop/pause and also progress bar. The option will be shown when we move our cursor at the bottom of the window. Do you have any idea how they were implemented those features?